# The scoring site keep saying that my code is exceeded time limit

Tags: c

well, I tried to solve problem Find the Cow! [Brian Dean, 2012]
I find it works well in "visual studio" and other IDE. But in "code up" the site which scores my code... it keeps saying that my code exceeded time limit...
Is there any problem with my code?

The problem is
PROBLEM NAME: cowfind

INPUT FORMAT:

- Line 1: A string of parentheses of length N (1 <= N <= 50,000).

SAMPLE INPUT (file cowfind.in):

```
)((()())())
```

OUTPUT FORMAT:

- Line 1: The number of possible positions at which Bessie can be
      standing -- that is, the number of distinct pairs of indices
      x < y at which there is the pattern (( at index x and the
      pattern )) at index y.

SAMPLE OUTPUT (file cowfind.out):

```
4
```

OUTPUT DETAILS:

There are 4 possible locations for Bessie, indicated below:

1.

```
)((()())())
 ^^   ^^
```

2.

```
)((()())())
  ^^  ^^
```

3.

```
)((()())())
  ^^     ^^
```

4.

```
)((()())())
 ^^      ^^
```

The code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #pragma warning(disable:4996)
    int main() {
        char c[50000];
        int i = 0;
        int j;
        int num = 0;
        while (scanf("%c", &c[i]) == 1)i++;
        c[i] = '\0';
        i = 0;


        while (c[i + 1] != '\0') {
                if ( (c[i] == c[i + 1]) && c[i] == '(') {
                j = i + 2;
                while (c[j + 1] != '\0') {
                    if ((c[j] == c[j + 1]) && c[j] == ')') {
                        num++;
                    }
                    j++;
                }
            }
            i++;
        }

        printf("%d", num);

    }
```

Comment: Tried using `strchr` instead of your tests?

Comment: @PhilM: The speed of locating a character in the string is not the problem.

Comment: Having a while loop inside a while loop means that for 50000 characters you are checking, on average, half of 50000*50000 characters to find positions. Plus you are reading the whole string into memory before processing it which uses a lot of memory.  You can do this with one while loop, two characters and two integers. Inside the while loop, read a character and if that one and the last are (( then you have found an open and if that one and the last are )) then you have found a close - simply add the opens to the total each time you find a close to find closes * number of opens found so far.

Comment: To reduce execution time, I'm pretty sure you can code the search part in only one while loop instead of two nested ones, Something like instead of `num++` you could have `num += numberOfPreviousOpeningParenthesis`.

Comment: rather than this time waster: `while (scanf("%c", &c[i]) == 1)i++;`  suggest a single call to `fgets( c, sizeof( c ), stdin );`

Comment: suggest implementing a simple state machine that keeps track of how many '((' followed by '))' have been seen in the input

Answer (score 1):

For many of these online judge problems, a key is to think of a better way to calculate the result. They are not challenging you just to write code but to think about how better algorithms can be designed.

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(void)
{
    long positions = 0; //  Count positions where Bessie may be standing.
    long opens = 0;     //  Count number of times "((" has been seen.
    char previous = 0;  //  Remember previous character.

    //  Loop reading characters.
    while (1)
    {
        //  Get next character.
        int next = getchar();

        //  If there was no next character or the line ended, we are done.
        if (next == EOF || next == '\n') break;

        //  Count the number of times "((" has been seen.
        if (next == '(' && previous == '(')
            ++opens;

        //  When we see "))", add one position for each "((" that precedes it.
        if (next == ')' && previous == ')')
            positions += opens;

        //  Remember the character for the next iteration.
        previous = next;
    }

    //  Show the result.
    printf("%ld\n", positions);
}
```

Comment: this is still inputting a single character at a time from the `stdin` I/O stream.  That is a real time waster.  Suggest read in the whole line in a single statement (like `fgets()` ) the do all the parsing in memory

Comment: @user3629249: Input with `getchar()` is buffered, and performance will be satisfactory. This code cures the major problem (O(n^2) complexity is reduced to to O(n)), which is the point of the exercise. There is no need to complicate the program further.

Comment: the function: `getchar()` still requires two swaps between the user code and the OS for every char.  Also, when using the online 'test' sites, a better function (requires a #define for the posix value)  is `getchar_unlocked()`  as that skips the io stream locking/unlocking/checking for the existence of a lock.   The function `fgets_unlocked()` results in a single swap to the OS and back to the user to acquire the whole line of data

Comment: @user3629249: As I wrote, `getchar` is buffered, at least in normal implementations. It does not require a system call on every call. And this sort of petty optimization is not the point of the problem. The complexity issue is.

Comment: the buffer is in the OS, not in the user space.  Also, the question is about taking to long to execute.  So the optimization(s) should be about making the code faster, not 'cuter'

Comment: @user3629249: C standard library implementations typically buffer. The buffer is in user space.